# arrows with xy package

Tags: xy-pic

I am trying, using the `xy` package, to make an arrow of the form `{>->}` with orientation "up-right" via `$\xymatrix@1{\ar@{>->}[ur]& }$`, but it is not operating. Would you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Isn't `$\nearrow$` something similar to what you want?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have an arrow pointing to the up right, you need at least two rows of matrix cells. I just added an empty row above and it works. I also inserted an example with [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) for demonstration. Different to `xymatrix`, you can't point to empty cells here. That's why I introduced the `\null` command, which is just an empty dummy.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix@1{
    & \\
    \ar@{>->}[ur] & 
}\]
\[\begin{tikzcd}%[row sep=..., column sep=...] & if you want to adapt size and angle
    & \null \\
    \ar[>->]{ur} &
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A short arrow can be obtained with `xy` rather than `\xymatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\newcommand{\nenearrow}{\mathrel{\donenearrow}}
\newcommand{\donenearrow}{%
  \kern 1mm
  \begin{xy} (-1,-1)="a",(2,2)="b" \ar@{>->} "a";"b" \end{xy}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
A \nenearrow B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]